# Copying multiple results based on a drop-down list

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I'm pretty new to creating Macros in Excel and using VBA.

Let's say I have a model based on a drop-down list. Based on the item selected from that list, model analyses according data and creates results. My point is to have these results compared for all the components from the list, in another sheet. The problem is that list includes around 200 item numbers.

What I need my macro to do is:

- Choose the item number from the drop-down list  in cell A1 in the "Sheet1"
- Copy the range A1:E2 in the "Sheet1"
- Paste the results to the Range A1:E1 in "Sheet2"
- Go back to "Sheet1" and choose next item from the list
- Copy the same range
- Paste it to "Sheet2" one row below the previous one (creating a list)
- And repeat the action until the last item on the list is used.

Does anybody have any advises how to write this macro down?

The task is by far exceeding my current programming skills. I searched everywhere, but couldn't find anything what would guide me into solution.

Comment: record a macro performing this task for the first two items. Then create a  loop to loop through all the items performing the required actions and use one of the many last row calculations to add 1 to to determine the next row to paste to https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm And put the copy range in a variable so you can refer back to this each time for your copy.

Comment: Is your dropdown data validation list or an embedded object e.g. listbox ?

Comment: It's data validation list

Comment: How is the data validation populated? do you write the list with commas separating, or is it referenced to a range?

Comment: @JoannaHorodko This is not macro course, read rules, show us your best attempt.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented what you want on an Excel workbook with two sheets.  Download it here:

http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=05985444391023940738

Try this.  Does it do what you need?